# How to query a table with a composite primary key

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, plsql

Hello (I am a noob in this area), I have a MySQL database and it has the next tables:

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdlJn.png)

So there are 3 tables, the one called "**INGREDIENTES**" that has ingredients and the other one called "**RECETAS**" that has recipes in it. The way I am connecting the 2 tables is with a table called "**INGREDIENTES_RECETAS**", this table has a composite primary key "*id_ingrediente + id_receta*", because  a recipe can have an unknown number of ingredients.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to make a query that filters a recipe by a number of unknown ids of "*id_ingrediente*".

I was thinking about something like:

```
SELECT id_receta FROM INGREDIENTES_RECETAS WHERE id_ingrediente CONTAINS (89 AND 18);
```

I would like to solve this problem avoiding PL/SQL, using only SQL. Is it possible?

I am using this in an java app, so if there is a method of doing it programatically it will solve the problem too.

If I have to use PL/SQL, How can I call a "*Procedure*" in java, using the jdbc driver?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Is this on Oracle? I see you have MySQL tagged, but you mention not wanting to use PL/SQL...

Comment: I'm unclear what your are trying to achieve. Are you trying to get a list of recipes with certain ingredients?

Comment: This question has been alredy answered by "Peter Abolins" thank you for commenting. I am used to work with Oracle so I thought that MySQL has PL/SQL also, I guessed wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to find all recipes which contain all listed ingredients (possibly more than 2), then you can do the following. Note that the `HAVING` clause should be compared to the number of ingredients being checked, and the `IN` clause should contain all the id's of the ingredients.

```
SELECT 
    ir.id_receta
FROM 
    INGREDIENTES_RECETAS ir
WHERE 
    ir.id_ingrediente IN (89, 18)
GROUP BY 
    ir.id_receta
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 2;
```

**EDIT**

If you want to find all recipes which have at least one of the listed ingredients, change the last clause to:

```
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 0;
```

And... while some of the other solutions here provide this in a different manner, to find all the recipes which have exactly one of the listed ingredients, change the last clause to:

```
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I totally forgot about the "*group by*" and "*having count*", it was so easy... Thank you all for the quick answers!! <3

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for recipes that contain both ingredients 89 and 18, then join `INGREDIENTES_RECETAS` with itself to form pairs of ingredients on which you can filter:

```
SELECT ir1.id_receta
FROM INGREDIENTES_RECETAS ir1
INNER JOIN INGREDIENTES_RECETAS ir2 ON ir1.id_receta = ir2.id_receta
WHERE ir1.id_ingrediente = 89 AND ir2.id_ingrediente = 18;
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer also solves my problem but I'm not used to use that kind of joins so I can't understand that code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_receta FROM INGREDIENTES_RECETAS WHERE id_ingrediente IN (89, 18);
```

or

```
SELECT id_receta FROM INGREDIENTES_RECETAS WHERE (id_ingrediente = 89) OR (id_ingrediente = 18);
```

Comment: This query shows all recipes that contains either id 89 or id 18, so it is not an exclusive OR (NOR)... I mean you are taking each id appart when I am trying to take each id in the same group like: show me a recipe with this 2 ingredients or show me nothing, but than you for your time

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a list of `id_receta` where the `id_ingrediente` matches a given list of IDs. This can be accomplished with.

```
SELECT
   `id_receta`
FROM
    `ingredients_recetas`
WHERE
    `id_ingrediente` IN (89, 18);
```

Comment: This query shows all recipes that contains either id 89 or id 18, so it is not an exclusive OR (NOR)... But thank you